# functions gets the value true even when there is no value

Tags: php, html, email, get, isset

i am traing to send a mail with php and i wrote this:

```
<?php
function title()
{
if(isset($_GET['title']))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo "please write a title!";
    return false;
}
}

function mess()
{
if(isset($_GET['mess']))
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo "please write a messege!";
    return false;
}
}

if(mess() && title())
{
    mail("guycohen801@gmail.com", $_GET['title'], $_GET['mess']);
    echo "the mail has bees send!";
}

?>
<form action="ftp_mail.php" method="get">
the title:
<input type="text" name="title"  />
the messege:
<input type="text" name="mess" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

but even when i doesn't writing anything on `$_GET['mess']` and `$_GET['title']` the functions `mess()` and `title()`
gets the value true.
please help!!

Comment: You should also check for `empty`. The fields will be commited independently of their value. You also want to use a mailer-framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
if((isset($_GET['mess'])) && ($_GET['mess']!=""))
```

Comment: if the value is "" it counts as a value?

Comment: no it is strict check that if your variable is set and if it is not empty then it will execute ur if condition

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(empty($_POST['title']) && empty($_POST['mess']))
{
    echo "please fill all the fields";
} 
else 
{
    $title = str_replace(array("\r","\n"), "", $_POST['title']);
    mail("email", $title, $_GET['mess']);
    echo "the mail has been sent";
}
```

Note that it have to be POST form, not GET.